# How to calculate a win streak in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the win-streak or losing-streak going into a game. My goal is to generate a betting decision based on these streak factors or a recent record. I am new to Python and Pandas (and programming in general), so any detailed explanation of what code does would be welcome.

Here's my data

```
    Season               Game Date                   Game Index  Away Team               Away Score  Home Team             Home Score  Winner                Loser
 0  2014 Regular Season  Saturday, March 22, 2014    2014032201  Los Angeles Dodgers              3  Arizona D'Backs                1  Los Angeles Dodgers   Arizona D'Backs
 1  2014 Regular Season  Sunday, March 23, 2014      2014032301  Los Angeles Dodgers              7  Arizona D'Backs                5  Los Angeles Dodgers   Arizona D'Backs
 2  2014 Regular Season  Sunday, March 30, 2014      2014033001  Los Angeles Dodgers              1  San Diego Padres               3  San Diego Padres      Los Angeles Dodgers
 3  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033101  Seattle Mariners                10  Los Angeles Angels             3  Seattle Mariners      Los Angeles Angels
 4  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033102  San Francisco Giants             9  Arizona D'Backs                8  San Francisco Giants  Arizona D'Backs
 5  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033103  Boston Red Sox                   1  Baltimore Orioles              2  Baltimore Orioles     Boston Red Sox
 6  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033104  Minnesota Twins                  3  Chicago White Sox              5  Chicago White Sox     Minnesota Twins
 7  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033105  St. Louis Cardinals              1  Cincinnati Reds                0  St. Louis Cardinals   Cincinnati Reds
 8  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033106  Kansas City Royals               3  Detroit Tigers                 4  Detroit Tigers        Kansas City Royals
 9  2014 Regular Season  Monday, March 31, 2014      2014033107  Colorado Rockies                 1  Miami Marlins                 10  Miami Marlins         Colorado Rockies
```

Dictionary below:

```
{'Away Score': {0: 3, 1: 7, 2: 1, 3: 10, 4: 9},
 'Away Team': {0: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  1: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  2: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  3: 'Seattle Mariners',
  4: 'San Francisco Giants'},
 'Game Date': {0: 'Saturday, March 22, 2014',
  1: 'Sunday, March 23, 2014',
  2: 'Sunday, March 30, 2014',
  3: 'Monday, March 31, 2014',
  4: 'Monday, March 31, 2014'},
 'Game Index': {0: 2014032201,
  1: 2014032301,
  2: 2014033001,
  3: 2014033101,
  4: 2014033102},
 'Home Score': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 8},
 'Home Team': {0: "Arizona D'Backs",
  1: "Arizona D'Backs",
  2: 'San Diego Padres',
  3: 'Los Angeles Angels',
  4: "Arizona D'Backs"},
 'Loser': {0: "Arizona D'Backs",
  1: "Arizona D'Backs",
  2: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  3: 'Los Angeles Angels',
  4: "Arizona D'Backs"},
 'Season': {0: '2014 Regular Season',
  1: '2014 Regular Season',
  2: '2014 Regular Season',
  3: '2014 Regular Season',
  4: '2014 Regular Season'},
 'Winner': {0: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  1: 'Los Angeles Dodgers',
  2: 'San Diego Padres',
  3: 'Seattle Mariners',
  4: 'San Francisco Giants'}}
```

I've tried looping through the season and the team, and then creating a streak count based on [this]: https://github.com/nhcamp/EPL-Betting/blob/master/EPL%20Match%20Results%20DF.ipynb github project.

I run into key errors early in building my loops, and I have trouble identifying data

```
game_table = pd.read_csv('MLB_Scores_2014_2018.csv')

# Get Team List
team_list = game_table['Away Team'].unique()

# Get Season List
season_list = game_table['Season'].unique()

#Defining "chunks" to append gamedata to the total dataframe
chunks = []

for season in season_list:
    # Looping through seasons. Streaks reset for each season
    season_games = game_table[game_table['Season'] == season]

    for team in team_list:
        # Looping through teams
        season_team_games = season_games[(season_games['Away Team'] == team | season_games['Home Team'] == team)]

        #Setting streak list and streak counter values
        streak_list = []
        streak = 0

        # Looping through each game
        for game in season_team_games.iterrow():
            # Check if team is a winner, and up the streak
            if game_table['Winner'] == team:
                streak_list.append(streak)
                streak += 1
            # If not the winner, append streak and set to zero
            elif game_table['Winner'] != team:
                streak_list.append(streak)
                streak = 0
            # Just in case something wierd happens with the scores
            else:
                streak_list.append(streak)
        game_table['Streak'] = streak_list
        chunk_list.append(game_table)
```

And that's kind of where I lose it. How do I append separately if each team is the home team or the away team? Is there a better way to display this data?

As a general matter, I want to add a win-streak and/or losing-streak for each team in each game. Headers would look like this:

| Season | Game Date | Game Index | Away Team | Away Score | Home Team | Home Score | Winner | Loser | Away Win Streak | Away Lose Streak | Home Win Streak | Home Lose Streak |

Edit: this error message has been resolved

I also get an error creating the dataframe 'season_team_games."

`TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]`

Comment: Can you add your example data and output as text? 5 rows will do (of both) I think this is a case for `groupby` `cumsum` and `transform`. Looking at your data it might possible needed to be `unstacked` first but I think others will be able help easily if you provide text data for them to work with.

Comment: Thank you- I've added the example data. Output data is a little harder since I can't actually get the code to complete, and with a small data sample of 10 records, It's a lot of 1's and 0's, and not in a good way.

Comment: that's perfect, my laptop is in for repair so I can't answer right now but if its not answered by tomorrow morning I will do it from my pc, best of luck, hopefully someone else picks this up!

Comment: can you print `df.head(5).to_dict()` and paste it in the question? having trouble using your code example

Comment: Sure- I've just updated the question. It looks like this is only the team and score data. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing come from the statement

```py
season_team_games = season_games[(season_games['Away Team'] == team | season_games['Home Team'] == team)]
```

When you're adding two boolean conditions, you need to separate them out with parentheses. This is because the `|` operator takes precedence over the `==` operator.  So this should become:

```py
season_team_games = season_games[(season_games['Away Team'] == team) | (season_games['Home Team'] == team)]
```

I know there is more to the question than this error, but as mentioned in the comment, once you provide some text based data, it might be easier to help